# Count data read from JSON

Tags: json, swift

This code reads from a database an ID and movie genre. I need to iterate through this information and count the id/genres information. I have it hardcoded now:

```
  let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=818396bc0172f0f1d446cb4ffc92b7d8&language=en-US")
  do {
    let allData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
    let info = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
    if let results = info["genres"] {
      print(results)
        for x in 0...18 { // here
          let id = results[x] as! [String : AnyObject]
          print(id)
      }
    }
  } catch {
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `for (key, value) in results { ... }`? That should give you access to all key / value pairs in that particular json object.

Comment: You are looking for the "for-in"/"for each" loop equivalent in Swift (that would have been the key word that you were looking for for your research): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 1):

I see the `genres` is a JSONArray, so you should cast it as an array of dictionary and use `for - in` to access each item in that array:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=818396bc0172f0f1d446cb4ffc92b7d8&language=en-US")
do {
    let allData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
    let info = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
    if let results = info["genres"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        print(results)
        for id in results {
            print(id)
        }
    }
} catch {
}
```